# are there any specific settings that I need to look at when using github actions' pull_request event?

Tags: github-actions

I have been trying to get the `pull_request` action to work but even though this is so basic I am not triggering the workflow. I can only trigger the workflow when I use `pull_request_target`

Previously I have defined types, paths, and branches. But in an attempt to troubleshoot the issue I removed everything and just ended up with `pull_request` to see if it really triggers if there are no filters. But the workflow still does not trigger on new PRs or reopened PRs (which I believe is the default when no event types are defined)

```
on: [pull_request]
```

Since this does not work also, I am inclined to assume that the issue is somewhere else

The target branch is in our team's repo and the source branch is my fork of the target branch

By this point I am suspecting that maybe it's a configuration either on the repo where the target branch is or the fork but I am not sure. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Add the full github workflow, perhaps you have an error there...

Answer (score 1):

as it turns out workflows when PRs come from forks is disabled on github by default. Enabling this fixed our issue.

Note: Github has this disabled by default to prevent hijacking of the repo through malicious PRs. But in our case this should be ok (for now) since were a very small team working on a private repo